# Why this doesn't work with recompose and ramda?

Tags: reactjs, ramda.js, recompose

In my hoc I have this conditional;

```
   branch(R.propSatisfies(R.isEmpty, "repos"), renderComponent(Loader)),
// branch(R.isEmpty("repos"), renderComponent(Loader)),
```

What's the difference and why the socond one gives me an error? `test is not a function`

Same result with this as well:

```
branch(R.isEmpty(R.props("repos")), renderComponent(Loader)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R. IsEmpty` is unary function that reports whether a value is the empty value for its type (such as empty string, empty object, or empty array.). When you call it with `"repos"`, you will get `false` since `"repos"` is not the empty string. Presumably the `branch` function you call wants a predicate function as the first argument and it fails when you send this boolean. Similarly, since `R. props` (you probably meant `R.prop` BTW, but the same issue would apply) is a binary function, `R.props("repos")` returns a function, which is not empty, so `isEmpty` returns false.

`R.propSatisfies`, on the other hand, is a ternary function accepting a predicate function, a property name, and an object.  When you call it with `isEmpty` and `"repos"`, you get back a function waiting for the object.  That gets passed to `branch` and all is good.

Is there a reason you don't like the `propSatisfies` version?

Comment: thanks for your explanation. No, I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `R.propSatisfies` has a different method signature to that of `R.isEmpty`.

In the case of your first approach:

```
branch(R.propSatisfies(R.isEmpty, "repos"), renderComponent(Loader))
```

the `R.propSatisfies` function is evaluating a function (`R.isEmpty`) on a property (`"repos"`) of the input object (ie which is the object returned from `renderComponent(Loader)`).

In the case of your second approach:

```
// branch(R.isEmpty("repos"), renderComponent(Loader)),
```

what you're doing here is calling `R.isEmpty` directly. The `R.isEmpty` method expects an array, and returns true if the supplied array is empty. `R.isEmpty` doesn't have the ability to determine if a property (ie "repos") in an object is empty or not. To make it easier to visualise what's going on here, consider the following:

```
// Your second approach:
branch(R.isEmpty("repos"), renderComponent(Loader))

// ...which when expanded, is equivalent to this. You can now see it 
// shows incorrect usage of R.isEmpty
branch(component => R.isEmpty("repos")(component), renderComponent(Loader))
```

Hope this offers some clarification - for more information on `R.isEmpty`, [see this link](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isEmpty)

Comment: Somehow I didn't see this one when I posted mine, with the same info.  That's what I get for doing SO on my mobile.  @karolis2017: I'm going to delete my repetitive answer.  I'd suggest that you mark this one as the correct version.

Comment: (I can't delete the accepted answer.  But if you choose this one, I will try to do so later.)

Comment: Hi @ScottSauyet - not a problem (and yes, SO + mobile isn't the easiest of combinations ;-))